# How to remove an old inaccessible Linux distro?

Tags: kernel, partition, dual-boot

I had `Manjaro` and `Windows 10` *(dual boot)* on my hard drive.

I added a new SSD and a newer `windows 10` on that drive.

I managed to manually delete the older `Windows` files but I can't access the `Linux` files from `Windows`.

I'm planning to install `Linux-lite` distro on the new SSD but I want to remove the older `Linux` distro first *(to free some space)*.

I can't access Manjaro because i get an error

> > error : file `/boot/vmlinuz-4.19x86_64` not found
> > error : you need to load the kernal first

**How do I remove/access that old distro?**

Comment: Remove or access? These are two mutually exclusive options.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov , yeah I'm aware of that. That's why I said "'or" not "and". If any of the options is not possible, or if someone knows only one option. My end goal is to free unused space. Either by accessing and repatriationing or just removing the old distro completely.

Answer (score 1):

Some people on reddit recommended to delete the partition from windows disk management. Which I did.  Wasn't essentially what I wanted but I went with the easy route.

Comment: You wanted to do these without re-format on some reason? If yes: you can not access ext4 from windows, microsoft does not want it. There are many 3rd-party tools. The easiest is to get a command shell from your new distro, mount the old partition and `rm -rf *` in it.

Comment: You have a perfectionist-traditionalist soul, just like mine! Welcome in the ethernity. :-)

Comment: Running `rm -rf *` in Linux can wipe EVERYTHING if you have Windows partitions mounted. **Never never never** recommend this command to inexperienced users. I wouldn't run it anyways if I wanted to remove my Linux anyways. `dd` or simple `cat /dev/zero > /dev/partition_with_linux` is so much better.

Comment: @peterh Yeah I wasn't able to access which is why I posted this question. Eventually I deleted the partition and probably lost some data but I don't remember what I lost. Which is for the better I guess.

Comment: @peterh, well yes, you are absolutely correct! tbh I'm not sure which part of my post that made you think so.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, I do usually mount windows partition that has my data in it. However I wouldn't mount them if I'm not planning to stay. But yeah that's very important to know. I can't afford losing everything. Can I run these commands somehow in windows or I need a linux shell?